# ImmutablePropertyException periodically when changing enum field's value via Rational Team Concert API

Tags: rtc

Hitting this issue with changing certain enumeration-based fields in my new RTC work item for a RTC API tool I'm working on.

Basically, I get an ImmutablePropertyException the first time I change the field, but the next time it works without an exception.

Want to get rid of the exceptions. I'm using a value RTC is actually returning to me as a valid enum value for the field.

> Assigning RTC work item field: **odc.impact** a field value of ->
>   **Integrity** [odc.impact.literal.l4]
>
> EXCEPTION: Could not assign value,
>   even though it was found in the enumeration list:     [Unassigned,
>   Installability, Standards, Integrity]
>
> **com.ibm.team.repository.common.internal.ImmutablePropertyException**    at
>   com.ibm.team.repository.common.internal.util.ItemUtil$ProtectAdapter.notifyChanged(ItemUtil.java:2070)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:380)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.repository.common.model.impl.StringExtensionEntryImpl.setTypedValue(StringExtensionEntryImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.repository.common.model.impl.StringExtensionEntryImpl.setValue(StringExtensionEntryImpl.java:360)
>     at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.BasicEMap.putEntry(BasicEMap.java:303)
>     at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.BasicEMap.put(BasicEMap.java:584)    at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.util.BasicEMap$DelegatingMap.put(BasicEMap.java:799)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.repository.common.model.impl.ItemImpl.setStringExtension(ItemImpl.java:1228)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.impl.WorkItemImpl.setEnumeration(WorkItemImpl.java:3779)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.impl.WorkItemImpl.setValue(WorkItemImpl.java:2915)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   com.ibm.team.repository.common.internal.util.ItemStore$ItemInvocationHandler.invoke(ItemStore.java:597)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.setValue(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.rtc.vda.WorkItemInitialization.setAttributeValueEx(WorkItemInitialization.java:237)
>     at
>   com.rtc.vda.WorkItemInitialization.setAttributeValue(WorkItemInitialization.java:210)
>     at
>   com.rtc.vda.WorkItemInitialization.execute(WorkItemInitialization.java:186)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.workitem.client.WorkItemOperation.execute(WorkItemOperation.java:85)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.workitem.client.WorkItemOperation.doRun(WorkItemOperation.java:272)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.workitem.client.WorkItemOperation.run(WorkItemOperation.java:242)
>     at
>   com.ibm.team.workitem.client.WorkItemOperation.run(WorkItemOperation.java:189)
>     at com.rtc.vda.RTCUtilities.createWorkItem(RTCUtilities.java:191)   at
>   com.rtc.vda.RTCMain.main(RTCMain.java:178)
>
> Assigning: odc.impact -> Integrity [odc.impact.literal.l4]

This is the code snippet to set the enum value:

```
public boolean setAttributeValueEx (IWorkItem w, String attributeKey, String valueName) {

    // (REO) Get the attribute
    IAttribute a = customAttributesMap.get(attributeKey);

    // (REO) Buffer of valid values for error reporting
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        // (REO) Get the enumeration for this attribute from the repository (DO NOT CACHE IT OR YOU WILL HAVE PROBLEMS)
        IWorkItemClient workItemClient = (IWorkItemClient) rtcParameters.getTeamRepository().getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);
        IEnumeration<? extends ILiteral> rtcAttrEnumeration = workItemClient.resolveEnumeration(a, curMonitor);

        // (REO) Find an enum value that matches this string and assign it
        for (ILiteral literal : rtcAttrEnumeration.getEnumerationLiterals()) {
            String vName = literal.getName();
            String vId = literal.getIdentifier2().getStringIdentifier();
            b.append(",");
            b.append(vName);
            if (valueName.equalsIgnoreCase(vName)) {
                String msg2 = "Assigning: " + a.getIdentifier() + " -> " + vName + " [" + vId + "]";
                RTCMain.out(msg2);
                w.setValue(a, literal.getIdentifier2()); // (REO) SOURCE OF PERIODIC EXCEPTION
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        RTCMain.out("EXCEPTION: Could not assign value, even though it was found in the enumeration list:\n\t[" + b + "]");
        e.printStackTrace();
        RTCMain.out("");
        return false;
    }

    RTCMain.out("VALUE NOT FOUND: Valid values are:" + b);
    return false;
}
```

Anyone know why I'm getting the periodic ImmutablePropertyException for only some of the fields, and why it goes away on the second call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the **workingCopy**.getWorkItem() object passed in to the execute() call rather than a cached version in a member variable. The attributes on the workingCopy object are not immutable and work fine.

```
public class WorkItemCreator extends WorkItemOperation {

...

    @Override
    protected void execute(WorkItemWorkingCopy workingCopy, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws TeamRepositoryException {

        IWorkItem newWorkItem = workingCopy.getWorkItem();
        // Set attribute values on newWorkItem to avoid ImmutablePropertyExceptions
```